# Symfony tests fail

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7.2

I wanted to contribute some code to Symfony 4. Therefore I followed the guide (https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/patches.html), forked Symfony and invoked the tests. The guide says "PHP 5.5.9 or above", however the tests fail due to PHP 7 new syntax. So I switched to PHP 7.2 running on Windows 7 x64.

When running `php ./phpunit symfony` before I touched any code lots of tests fail. Most tests fail with the message "Other deprecation notices":

```
Testing src/Symfony/Component/Messenger
..............                                                    14 / 14 (100%)

Time: 3.66 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB

OK (14 tests, 25 assertions)

Other deprecation notices (1)

  1x: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls

KO src/Symfony/Component/Messenger
```

at the end it says, that "OK but incomplete, ..."

```
Testing src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle
.............................................................   61 / 1083 (  5%)
.............................................................  122 / 1083 ( 11%)
.............................................................  183 / 1083 ( 16%)
.............................................................  244 / 1083 ( 22%)
.............................................................  305 / 1083 ( 28%)
.............................................................  366 / 1083 ( 33%)
.............................................................  427 / 1083 ( 39%)
.....................S.......................................  488 / 1083 ( 45%)
.............................................................  549 / 1083 ( 50%)
.............................................................  610 / 1083 ( 56%)
..................SS.........................................  671 / 1083 ( 61%)
.............................................................  732 / 1083 ( 67%)
.............................................................  793 / 1083 ( 73%)
.............................................................  854 / 1083 ( 78%)
.............................................................  915 / 1083 ( 84%)
.............................................................  976 / 1083 ( 90%)
............................................................. 1037 / 1083 ( 95%)
..............................................                1083 / 1083 (100%)

Time: 3.94 minutes, Memory: 108.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1083, Assertions: 2282, Skipped: 3.

Legacy deprecation notices (14)

Other deprecation notices (1)

  1x: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls

KO src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle
```

Also there are "real" errors:

```
1) Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Tests\Encoder\Argon2iPasswordEncoderTest::testValidationWithConfig
password_hash(): Memory cost is outside of allowed memory range

C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\Argon2iPasswordEncoder.php:105
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\Argon2iPasswordEncoder.php:67
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Tests\Encoder\Argon2iPasswordEncoderTest.php:34
```

or here:

```
1) Symfony\Component\Console\Tests\Helper\QuestionHelperTest::testAskChoice
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException: Aborted

C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:118
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:67
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:369
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:70
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Console\Tests\Helper\QuestionHelperTest.php:89
```

or here:

```
1) Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Tests\Dumper\ServerDumperTest::testDump
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException: The process "C:\Software\Development\Php7\php.exe" exceede
d the timeout of 9 seconds.

C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Process\Process.php:1154
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Process\Process.php:383
C:\Daten\Projekte\2018\dev\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Tests\Dumper\ServerDumperTest.php:92
```

Comment: "Memory cost is outside of allowed memory range" "exceeded the timeout of 9 seconds." - Those error messages should give you a clue what's going on, at least with those tests. Increase the memory limit and timeout.

Comment: There is no timeout in CLI mode and my memory limit is set to infinite

Comment: `each()` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2. Make sure your Symfony is recent. I went through the code on Github and I can't see them using this function anymore on Master branch.

Comment: Well *something* is timing out. Go through the code and see what it is and if it can be fixed. As for the memory limit, it could very well be possible that password_hash is using more memory than you have available on your system if it's using Argon2. You would have to tweak the options sent to password_hash() to fix this.